# Is there a way to fetch a specific tag from a remote git repository using libgit2sharp ?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I set up a remote called 'origin' and clone the remote into the local directory with checkout set to false so I can fetch the remote tags. I can list the remote tags but I can't find any way to fetch the contents.

If I call clone with checkout set to true, I get the HEAD which is great but I'd like to be able to roll back to a specific tagged version and can't see how.

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout any arbitrary commit, including a tag (for instance: '`lw`'):

```
string commitPointer = refs/tags/lw;
var commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commitPointer);
Branch detachedHead = repo.Checkout(commitPointer);
```

You will be in a detached head though:

```
Assert.Equal("(no branch)", detachedHead.CanonicalName);
Assert.False(master.IsCurrentRepositoryHead);
Assert.True(repo.Info.IsHeadDetached);
```

But that HEAD does reference your tag:

```
Assert.True(detachedHead.IsCurrentRepositoryHead);
Assert.Equal(repo.Head, detachedHead);
Assert.Equal(commit.Sha, detachedHead.Tip.Sha);
Assert.True(repo.Head.IsCurrentRepositoryHead);
Assert.False(repo.Index.RetrieveStatus().IsDirty);

Assert.False(detachedHead.IsRemote);
Assert.Equal(detachedHead.Name, detachedHead.CanonicalName);
```

See more at "[`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CheckoutFixture.cs#CanCheckoutAnArbitraryCommit()`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/ad12cca3ba989659b0189df36b47e4e8121d2976/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CheckoutFixture.cs#L96-L142)"